# Login within Facebook App iFrame

Tags: facebook

I'm having some trouble with Facebook App logins.

I can redirect the user ok to the Auth Dialog Permissions box and authorise it, which then goes to https://apps.facebook.com/my_app/start.php, now on start.php i have a standard form which POSTs data to itself to log the user into our own auth system (through an API), now I'm receiving "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.". Is this because I cannot POST data within the iFrame to our API?

What is the usual workflow here?

Do I need to open a new window and redirect the user back to the app once they've logged in to our own system?

Any advice appreciated!

I'm using the PHP SDK from FB by the way...

Answer (score 0):

> now I'm receiving "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.". Is this because I cannot POST data within the iFrame to our API?

No, this is because your server tells the client browser via a HTTP header that the resource is not allowed to be displayed in (i)frames on external domains.

So stop your server sending this header if you want to use your pages inside an iframe on Facebook.

http://www.google.com/search?q=X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

If anyone is interested, this is the form markup that worked:

```
<form target="iframe_canvas_fb_https" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

target is name of the iframe that your app is sat in.